# How to create chart with MTD and Eomonth value in power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-custom-visuals

The chart I created already has all the EOM and MTD values, now I 'd like to just show/filter MTD & EOM value with x - axis is the last working day of the month (I mean only show the circled in red in the image below).

MTD value is the number of new deposits accumulated at the end of the month, and EOM value is the number of outstanding customer deposits each month.
I created 1 measure MTD:
`New outstanding amount MTD = TOTALMTD(SUM(Data[OS]), Data[Date])`

[image]

I don't want to filter day by day like the picture, is there a better way?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DAX [time-intelligence functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/time-intelligence-functions-dax) allow you to manipulate the time period over which an expression is calculated.

`DATESBETWEEN()` returns all dates between two inputs. When the first date input is set to `BLANK()`, the output date range will begin at the earliest date.

```
Prior Week Percentage of missing product = 
CALCULATE(
    SUM(Data[OS]),
    DATESBETWEEN( 'Calendar'[Date], BLANK(), LASTDATE( 'Calendar'[Date] ) )
)
```

This returns the sum of all outstanding deposits from the beginning of time to the last date in context.

---EDIT-----------------------

Per OP edit, you will need a month column on your date table to aggregate by month. Your MTD measure will continue to work, and this measure will continue to work. One thing I've learned about creating month columns is that it is best to use the first day of the month (`EOMONTH( 'Calendar'[Date], -1 ) + 1`). Using the last day of the month aligns the data point so close to the label for the first day of the following month that it can make your chart difficult to read.

---EDIT 2---------------------

To find the value just on the last day of the month, you can just use the `LASTDATE()` function alone.

```
CALCULATE(
    SUM(Data[OS]),
    LASTDATE( 'Calendar'[Date] )
)
```

This will find the last date in context, and return the value only on that day. As long as your visual is summarizing by month, this will work.

Comment: I just reworded the content, Are you clarify what I mean?

Comment: The way i read your comment edit was that you want to see a bar chart with monthly columns for the month's deposits, and an all time running balance of deposits. Is that correct? Is that correct? Did my answer (with subsequent edit) work for you?

Comment: Your answer is great only when applied to MTD value, but what about the rest, I need the value at the end of the month, just the value at the end of the month, not adding other the days of the month (the dark blue bar chart)

Comment: I see now, does my last edit do what you are expecting?